# Why GPS is still in usage eventhough i removed location updates for fused location api in android

Tags: android, gps

I am using Fused Location Api for location updates in my app. When I request for location updates, GPS is getting ON(we can see location symbol in status bar) and when I am removing location updates by calling removeLocationUpdates,sometimes GPS is not switching off(we can see still location symbol in status bar).No other app is using GPS at this point of time other than my app.
This is resulting in consuming more battery by the app.

**Creating required object instances**

```
  mLocationClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(connectCallbackListener)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(connectFailedListnr)
                .addApi(LocationServices.API).build();

    mLocationRequest = LocationRequest.create();
    mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
    mLocationRequest.setInterval(UPDATE_INTERVAL_IN_MILLISECONDS);
    mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(FASTEST_INTERVAL_IN_MILLISECONDS);
```

**Requesting for location updates**

```
LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mLocationClient, mLocationRequest, mLocationListener);
```

**Removing location updates**

```
if (mLocationClient.isConnected()) {
            LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.removeLocationUpdates(mLocationClient, mLocationListener);
 }
 mLocationClient.disconnect();
```

Anyone has any idea about this issue ?

Comment: *No other app is using GPS at this point of time other than my app* how would you know?

Comment: Because whenever I delete my app or clear data of my app then GPS is getting OFF(we can't see location symbol in status bar, it is getting removed)

Comment: More code where you show how / where you call the start and stop methods might help in tracking down why.

Comment: Did anyone resolve this issue? I have the same problem here. I'm not using a LocationListener, or PendingIntent which receivin updates. I'm just calling LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(googleApiClient); Im also disconnecting googleApiClient onStop()

Comment: same issue here. anyone has solve this? disconnect not help, icon still in status bar.

Comment: In my case following this codelabs solve my issue: https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/background-location-updates-android-o/index.html . Hope this help someone else. Tks

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. Not FusedLocationApi is keeping the GPS running, even if the App is put to background and onStop() was fired. It's GoogleMap!! I had included a Map in another Fragment and didn't recognized for a while. I think also Renadh has a GoogleMap View included.

So, to only keep GPS running in your App while it is running put

```
@Override
public void onStop() {
    mGoogleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(false);
    super.onStop();
}
```

to your Fragment/Activity.

Don't forget to enable your location with

```
mGoogleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
```

if you require the blue marker in your mapview. Either in onCreate() or wherever you set up your map.